# Would I still hold reference to the owner of the Consumer if the listener that triggers the Consumer is enclosed by a WeakReference?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, reference, weak-references, consumer

Like this:

Proc is a functional interface type void.

```
public class MainViewPagerViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> quantities = new HashMap<>();
    private WeakReference<Proc> weakProc;

    public void put(Integer position, Integer quantity) {
        quantities.put(position, quantity);
        if (weakProc.get() != null) {
            weakProc.get().run();
        }
    }

    public void updatePieChart(Consumer<HashMap<Integer, Integer>> mapConsumer) {
        weakProc = new WeakReference<>(
                () -> mapConsumer.accept(quantities)
        );
    }

}
```

Will this work, or I'm I still holding reference to the Consumer's onwer? or... is this too much? maybe this is enough?

```
    public void updatePieChart(Consumer<HashMap<Integer, Integer>> mapConsumer) {
        
            proc = () -> mapConsumer.accept(quantities)
      
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Proc is a functional interface type void_ - you mean `Runnable`? can you make it clear in the question? This entire question makes no sense, can you explain in plain english what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a very general advice that needs to be in place here: unless you know what some constructs do (`WeakReference` in this case), don't use it. Study it's documentation, run more than just one example and when you are comfortable with it - use it. `WeakReference`s are a sharp tool, and you need to know all the problems and issue you might encounter. Here are a few intros about what it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52789834/is-weakhashmap-ever-growing-or-does-it-clear-out-the-garbage-keys/57876763#57876763), [or here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992402/if-javas-generational-garbage-collectors-traverse-the-graph-of-live-objects-ho/60628818#60628818) or [may be even here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791900/how-finalizable-objects-takes-at-least-2-garbage-collection-cycles-before-it-can/60628663#60628663).

And now - what are you trying to solve, specifically? Is your code broken *without* that wrapper around `Proc`: `private WeakReference<Proc> weakProc;`? I don't think it is.

By introducing that `WeakReference` it's like you are saying that `Proc` (which is a `Runnable` defined as a lambda expression) will be GCed, while the `MainViewPagerViewModel` is still alive. And now ask yourself - is that even possible? Forget about `WeakReference` here for a second. Can `proc` be garbage collected at some point in time *while* `MainViewPagerViewModel` is still going to be alive? If that is the case - what would happen when you would call `put`?

When you have the answer to the above, you will understand that your question makes somehow very little sense; and the introduction of `WeakReference` there is useless.

Comment: Yes, it does make little to no sense, ViewModel will survive the class consuming the hashmap... definitely.
I think my confusion is a matter of meaning/definition.
Is it _holding_ reference, or to _be held_ in a reference, who is the responsible and who is the affected, what is the cause of an effect that involves 2 equally synergistic environments, where the consumption of one is the production of another (another concept that I cannot fully grasp)
My concern is that the class where the consumer is created new is held by the viewmodel that will survive it.

Comment: @Delark Ive read your comment a few times, but I can't make much sense out of it. What if you try to break things down, to smaller questions/examples?

Comment: I dont know how to ask...
Something tells me that there may be a situation where Consumers/Functions, and or listeners, may cause Memory leaks and I don't know which or how.